# How do I list FFMPEG's audio formats?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, format

I'm trying to ask FFMPEG for all the audio formats it can encode.

I can get a list of formats with `ffmpeg -formats`:

```
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
 D  3dostr          3DO STR
  E 3g2             3GP2 (3GPP2 file format)
  E 3gp             3GP (3GPP file format)
 D  4xm             4X Technologies
  E a64             a64 - video for Commodore 64
 D  aa              Audible AA format files
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
...
```

This shows me formats that it can encode/decode, but it's impossible to tell which are audio formats and which are video formats.

I can get a list of codecs using `ffmpeg -codecs`:

```
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression
 -------
 D.VI.. 012v                 Uncompressed 4:2:2 10-bit
 D.V.L. 4xm                  4X Movie
 D.VI.S 8bps                 QuickTime 8BPS video
 .EVIL. a64_multi            Multicolor charset for Commodore 64 (encoders: a64multi )
 .EVIL. a64_multi5           Multicolor charset for Commodore 64, extended with 5th color (colram) (encoders: a64multi5 )
 D.V..S aasc                 Autodesk RLE
 D.VIL. aic                  Apple Intermediate Codec
 DEVI.S alias_pix            Alias/Wavefront PIX image
...
```

This shows me a list of "codecs" and whether or not they are for audio/video, but these aren't formats and thus aren't suitable for using with the `-f` flag.

For example, here's an audio codec but it doesn't work:

`DEA.L. speex                Speex (decoders: libspeex ) (encoders: libspeex )`

`C:\test>ffmpeg -i uwu.mp3 -f speex out.x`

```
[NULL @ 00000000025ca260] Requested output format 'speex' is not a suitable output format
out.x: Invalid argument
```

So how can I get a list of **formats** from this thing that tell me whether or not they are audio formats?

Comment: There are few audio-only containers accommodating multiple codecs, e.g. WAV. Most are simple encapsulations for a single codec e.g. MP3, FLAC.